# Do you have any source about the connection between אגג and גוג or גוג ומגוג?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, purim, chasidut-hasidism, gematria-numerology, gog

I was listening to a shiur that made a very interesting connection between Agag, Homon and the whole Purim story. The rov didn't go as deep as I hoped he would in relation to Agag, and I was wondering if you're aware of any source connecting Agag to Gog or Gog umagog as a whole.